# Creating Dynamic Distribution Group with EmployeeType AD Attribute

Tags: powershell, exchange-server-2010

We have been asked if a DDG can be created based on what is entered into the Users EmployeeType AD attribute.  Scripting DDG knowledge is very limited and Exchange isn't my normal area of responsibilities, apologies for the newbie question.

Comment: According to [Filterable Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/exchange/exchange-server/recipient-filters/recipientfilter-properties?view=exchange-ps), `employeeType` is not filterable in a recipient filter. So you will need to either utilize another attribute like one of the `CustomAttribute*` or use another process to update group membership.

Answer (score 0):

The question is lacking in detail in order to give an exceptional answer. However, here is an idea that may help get you started.

What you are hoping to do is to use the `-RecipientFilter` parameter of [New-DynamicDistributionGroup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/users-and-groups/new-dynamicdistributiongroup?view=exchange-ps). The parameter supports an OPATH filter with limited [filterable properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/exchange/exchange-server/recipient-filters/recipientfilter-properties?view=exchange-ps) and comparison operators. According to the documentation, `employeeType` is ***not*** filterable with the OPATH filter.

As an alternative, you could have an automated or scripted process that updates an attribute that can be conditionally queried by the dynamic group. Here is an example of using the `employeeType` to update `extensionAttribute1`.

```
Get-AdUser -Filter "employeeType -eq 'Vendor'" |
    Set-AdUser -Replace @{'extensionAttribute1' = 'Vendor'}
```

Then you can create a dynamic distribution group based on `ConditionalCustomAttribute1`, which maps to `extensionAttribute1` in AD.

```
New-DynamicDistributionGroup -Name "Vendor Dynamic Group" -IncludedRecipients "MailboxUsers" -ConditionalCustomAttribute1 "Vendor"
```

Note that you can query for more than one value since `-ConditionalCustomAttribute1` accepts an array. So you could pass `-ConditionalCustomAttribute1 "Vendor","Contractor"`, which would look for the values `Vendor` or `Contractor` in `extensionAttribute1`.